# Convert quarters to long date using Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to convert the values within a specific column to a long date.
The long date will always be the first of the first month of that quarter.

```
**Ex. Q122 = 1/1/2022,   Q222 = 4/1/2022,  Q322 = 7/1/2022,  Q422 = 10/1/2022**
```

**Data**

```
ID   Date   Location

AA   Q123   NY
BB   Q425   CA
CC   Q226   NY
CC   Q326   NY
```

**Desired**

```
ID   Date   Location   LongDate

AA   Q123   NY         1/1/2023
BB   Q425   CA         10/1/2025
CC   Q226   NY         4/1/2026
CC   Q326   NY         7/1/2026
```

**Doing**

```
df['Date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(qs, freq='Q').to_timestamp()
```

Error is unable to parse. I am thinking there has to be initial conversion here. Researching this, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to write your own parsing function. Take the first two characters and assign month/day, then take the last two and assign the year. Combine and convert to datetime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do with reversing the pattern:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str[-2:]+df['Date'].str[:2]).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

---

```
0    01/01/2023
1    10/01/2025
2    04/01/2026
3    07/01/2026
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Note that `.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` should be only used if you want them as strings. I recommend you dont use them and let it be date

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. I was wondering does this also preserve the original columns? This works, however my original columns are now removed @anky

Comment: @Lynn you can assign this to a new column -> `df['LongDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].str[-2:]+df['Date'].str[:2]).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
`